# Questions about conforming to legislation such as CE-marking - on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, acceptable-questions

For example, should my following question be on-topic? I have desperately looked for places to ask such questions, and was the main reason for joining the Engineering SE site (among others with fingers crossed)

[CE Marking on low budgets: conforming to EMI / EMC requirements in ELV and mains circuits](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86/ce-marking-on-low-budgets-conforming-to-emi-emc-requirements-in-elv-and-mains)

Comment: This was  a great question. EMI EMC is EE as well as ME issue. University of Wisconsin has course both for EE and ME. http://epdweb.engr.wisc.edu/Courses/Course.lasso?myCourseChoice=P724

Answer (score 14):

Conforming to legislation is an important part of engineering.

I would expect to be able to ask and answer questions about engineering legislation on this site; from how to comply, to what our duties are.

The fact that an engineer has been able to answer your question, further confirms this; in my view.

Answer (score 2):

In this case they're specifying EMI/EMC, in which case it could go here or possibly do better on EE.SE.

That said, as the answer to that question points out with LVD, EMI/EMC isn't all there is to getting a CE mark. Depending on the type of device, the safety requirements (61010-1 etc) can be a bigger hurdle than EMI/EMC and encompass more than just EE issues alone.